# Simple Size Change in CSS Document for Comment Box

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the size of this facebook style comment box. I don't have any experience or knowledge of CSS and I couldn't figure out which CSS block to modify. Thanks in advance. I have included the CSS file and the file that utilizes the CSS specs. Thanks again.

```
    .emAddComment{
    background-color: #ECEFF5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5EAF1;
    clear: left;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 15px 4px 5px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}

input.emButton{
    padding: 2px 4px 3px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    width: auto;
}

span.emButton{
    background-color: #5B74A8;
    border-color: #29447E #29447E #1A356E;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: medium none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.emAddComment textarea{
    width: 50%;
    height: 29px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 10px 5px 0;
    min-height: 29px;
    border: 1px solid #BDC7D8;
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.emAddComment .addEmMail, .emAddComment .addEmName{
    margin: 0 10px 5px 0;
    border: 1px solid #BDC7D8;
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 200px;
}

.emAddComment label{
    width: 75px;
    text-align: right;
}

.emComment{
    background-color: #ECEFF5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5EAF1;
    clear: left;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 0 4px 5px;
    display: block;
    color: #333;
}

.emInfoMessage{
    background-color: #FFEFF5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5EAF1;
    clear: left;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 0 4px 5px;
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.emComment .emCommentImage{
    float: left;
}

.emComment .emCommentText{
    padding-right: 7px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.emComment .emCommentInto{
    color: #777;
    padding: 7px 7px 1px;
    text-align: right;
}

.emShowAllComments, .emHideAllComments{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5EAF1;
    clear: left;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 0 4px 5px;
    display: block;
    color: #333;

    background: #ECEFF5 url('images/comments.png') no-repeat 5px 4px;
    padding-left: 26px;
}

#emContent, .emContent{
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#emContent a, .emContent a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3B5998;
}

#emContent a:hover, .emContent a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.emSenderName{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.emAddComment .addEmPot{
    display: none;
}

.emCommentLike{
    margin-top: 5px; 
    color: #777;
}

<?php
require_once('commentanything/config.inc.php');
require_once('commentanything/funcs.inc.php');



## check if there is a moderation action ###
#
$actionType     = null;
$actionComleted = false;
if($_GET['emAct'] and $_GET['emCommentKey'] and $_GET['emCommentID'] and $_GET['emCommentOID']){
    //check if the comment exists and I have access
    if($comment = $db->query("SELECT * FROM em_comments WHERE id = ".(int)$_GET['emCommentID']." AND object_id = ".(int)$_GET['emCommentOID']." AND access_key = ".$db->quote($_GET['emCommentKey']))->fetch()){
        switch($_GET['emAct']){
            case 'delete':  {
                                $actionCompleted = true;
                                $actionType      = 'delete';
                                $db->query("DELETE FROM em_comments WHERE id = ".(int)$_GET['emCommentID']." AND object_id = ".(int)$_GET['emCommentOID']." AND access_key = ".$db->quote($_GET['emCommentKey']));
                                break;
                            }

            case 'allow':   {
                                $actionCompleted = true;
                                $actionType      = 'allow';
                                $db->query("UPDATE em_comments SET visible = '1' WHERE id = ".(int)$_GET['emCommentID']." AND object_id = ".(int)$_GET['emCommentOID']." AND access_key = ".$db->quote($_GET['emCommentKey']));
                                break;
                            }
        }
    }        
}
#
## end check ###############################



//get comments from database
$myip       = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$comments   = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT
                                em_comments.*,
                                em_likes.vote
                            FROM em_comments 
                            LEFT JOIN em_likes ON em_comments.id = em_likes.comment_id AND em_likes.sender_ip = ".$myip."                                    
                            WHERE 
                                object_id = ".$db->quote($object_id)." AND
                                visible   = '1'
                            ORDER BY id")->fetchAll();

// -- form output ------------------------------------------------
$total    = count($comments);
$counter  = 1;
$html     = '<div id="emContent_'.$object_id.'" class="emContent">';

if($actionCompleted){
    $html .= '<div class="emInfoMessage">';
    $html .= $lang['cid'].' '.(int)$_GET['emCommentID'].' '.$lang['wassuc'].' '.($actionType=='delete'?$lang['deleted']:$lang['moderated']).'!';
    $html .= '</div>';
}

if($total > $CCOUNT){
    $html .= '<div class="emShowAllComments" id="emShowAllComments_'.$object_id.'">
                <a href="javascript:viewAllComments(\''.$object_id.'\');">'.$lang['view'].' <span id="total_em_comments_'.$object_id.'">'.$total.'</span> '.$lang['view2'].'</a> <noscript><em>This page needs JavaScript to display all comments</em></noscript>
              </div>
              <div class="emHideAllComments" id="emHideAllComments_'.$object_id.'" style="display: none;">
                <a href="javascript:hideAllComments(\''.$object_id.'\');">'.$lang['hide'].' <span id="total_em_comments_to_hide_'.$object_id.'">'.$total.'</span> '.$lang['view2'].'</a>
              </div>';
}

foreach($comments as $comment){
    if($comment['sender_name']){
        if($comment['sender_mail']){
            $comment['sender_name'] = jsEncode($comment['sender_mail'], $comment['sender_name']);
        }
        $sender = '<span class="emSenderName">'.$comment['sender_name'].'</span>: ';
    }else{
        $sender = '';
    }


    if($comment['vote']){            
        $likeText = commentLikeText($comment['rating_cache']-1);
    }else{
        $likeText = '<a href="javascript:iLikeThisComment('.$comment['id'].')">'.$lang['ilike'].'</a>';
        if($comment['rating_cache']){
            $likeText .= ' &mdash; '.commentLikeText($comment['rating_cache'],false);
        }
    }


    $html .= '<div class="emComment emComment_'.$object_id.' '.($counter < ($total - ($CCOUNT - 1))?'emHiddenComment emHiddenComment_'.$object_id:'').'" id="comment_'.$comment['id'].'" '.($counter < ($total - ($CCOUNT - 1))?'style="display:none"':'').'>
                <div class="emCommentImage">
                    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.gravatar($comment['sender_mail'], false).'" width="32" height="32" alt="Gravatar" />
                </div>
                <div class="emCommentText">
                    '.$sender.stripslashes($comment['comment_text']).'                        
                </div>
                <div class="emCommentInto">                        
                    '.strftime($DATEFORMAT,strtotime($comment['created'])).'

                    <div class="emCommentLike" style="'.($ALLOWLIKE?'':'display:none;').'">
                        <span id="iLikeThis_'.$comment['id'].'">
                            <em>'.$likeText.'</em>                               
                        </span>
                    </div>

                </div>
              </div>';
    $counter++;
}
$html .= '</div>';


$html .= '<div id="emAddComment_'.$object_id.'" class="emAddComment">
            <form method="post" action="commentanything/php/addComment.php" onsubmit="return false;">
                <span '.($SHOWNAME?'':'style="display: none;"').' id="emNameSpan_'.$object_id.'" class="emNameSpan">
                    <label for="addEmName_'.$object_id.'">'.$lang['name'].':</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="'.$lang['enterName'].'" id="addEmName_'.$object_id.'" class="addEmName" name="sender_name" />
                </span>

                <span '.($SHOWMAIL?'':'style="display: none;"').' id="emMailSpan_'.$object_id.'">
                    <label for="addEmMail_'.$object_id.'">'.$lang['mail'].':</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="'.$lang['enterMail'].'" id="addEmMail_'.$object_id.'" class="addEmMail" name="sender_mail" />
                </span>

                <textarea placeholder="'.$lang['enterComment'].'" id="addEmComment_'.$object_id.'" class="addEmComment" name="comment"></textarea>

                <input type="text"   name="email"     value="" id="addEmPot_'.$object_id.'" class="addEmPot" />
                <input type="hidden" name="object_id" value="'.$object_id.'" />

                <span class="emButton">
                    <input type="submit" class="emButton" id="emAddButton_'.$object_id.'" value="'.$lang['comment'].'" onclick="addEMComment(\''.$object_id.'\')" />
                </span>
            </form>
          </div>';

//send reply to client
echo '<div id="'.$object_id.'" class="emComments" object="'.$object_id.'" class="ignorejsloader">'.$html.'</div>';
```

Comment: Make some sort of effort... People don't want to do the work for you. If you have a particular question, come back and post that. Otherwise, please don't post your entire code and say "do this for me".

Comment: Haha I did try. I tried online editors, looked up what some of these different features do etc. Do you feel like a big man now that you can tell people to make some effort?  I guess in my question it didn't sound like I had tried different things so I guess I can't really blame @DOM

Comment: No, just telling you most people won't give you the time of day (hence the downvotes).  Best of luck.

Comment: I know, I don't even know how the negative downvotes works. I know that the last few questions were pretty tough questions and I was researching and trying for more than a week before I posted them. Hmm maybe I need to figure out this voting system and make sure I don't get anymore negative feedbacks. I guess I have no other choice but to keep changing values until I get the right one and or learn css by looking up all the features used by this sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Trial/error is a way of learning. Try updating the width on the code below for instance:

```
.emAddComment textarea{
    width: 50%;
    height: 29px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 10px 5px 0;
    min-height: 29px;
    border: 1px solid #BDC7D8;
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for not assuming that I haven't tried. I had already tried what you suggested and it didn't change anything. Thanks through.